# Angular 2 - Select2 multiple and reactive forms

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angular-reactive-forms

I'm developing an Angular 2 application and I'm currently struggling with select2 (with multiple option set to true) (https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) and using it inside reactive forms. I found some customization in issues which looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/Gw36MB93

but when I actually put select2 inside a form and then print the value of the form on the page, select's value is an empty list. I guess ControlValueAccessor interface is not implemented entirely properly but after many attempts I didn't find any solution.

I use mentioned select2 component like this:

```
...
<select2 [data]="instruments" formArrayName="instruments" [options]="{multiple: true}"></select2>
...
```

By the way - I know I can get the value of my Select2Component like this `<select2 #select ...>` but actually I'm using Select2Component as a form field in FormArray. Just to be clear, my form looks like that:

```
<div [formGroup]="clientForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="first_name">
  <input type="text" formControlName="last_name">
  <app-events-array #events_array></app-events-array>
</div>
```

and `<app-events-array>` is the one that contains an array of events (user can add blank events and remove selected ones like in an usual formset):

```
<div [formGroup]="eventsForm">
  <p-calendar formControlName="start"></p-calendar>
  <p-calendar formControlName="end"></p-calendar>
  <select2 [data]="instruments" formArrayName="instruments" [options]="{multiple: true}"></select2>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, the only thing I can't get to work is this instruments select2 inside app-events-array. When I do `events_array.events.value` (where `.events` is a `FormArray`, I get an empty list, although there are options selected.

What am I missing?

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: why do not u use simple select with options?

Comment: if you mean sth like that: `<select multiple="multiple"></select>` then my answer is: because it's ugly and the end user won't ever accept such UI